# How do I pass list of checked checboxes to MVC controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am able to add the asp tag helpers asp-for to text input elements like this:

```
        <label asp-for="Year" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Year" type="text" class="form-control" id="Year" />
```

And I get the data in the controller.

But, how do you do the same for checkboxes that are checked like the ones below so that I can access them in the controller?

I am trying to bind all the checked checkboxes to this model property: `public List<string> PTList { get; set; }`

```
            <div class="col-3">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="U100" id="flexCheckDefault">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                        U100
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="U110" id="flexCheckChecked" checked>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
                        U110
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="U130" id="flexCheckDefault">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                        U130
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="U150" id="flexCheckChecked" checked>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
                        U150
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `name` atttribute to pass the checkbox value ,like

```
<div class="col-3">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="U100"  name="ck" id="flexCheckDefault">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                U100
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="U110"  name="ck"id="flexCheckChecked" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
                U110
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="U130" name="ck" id="flexCheckDefault">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                U130
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="U150" name="ck" id="flexCheckChecked" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
                U150
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Qing Guo, how are you connecting the name property to the model so that it can be passed to the controller? You are not using any tag helpers like asp-for.

Comment: Hi @martinb , I use `name`   HTML attribute  connecting the name property to the model so that it can be passed to the controller.  I  am not using any tag helpers like asp-for:  Generates the id and name HTML attributes for the expression name specified in the asp-for attribute.  You can read [The Input Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-7.0#the-input-tag-helper) to know more.

Answer (score 0):

To access values in the controller you can do the following:

**1. Make sure you have your html form properly set**

**2. Use the name attribute**

```
<form action="/your-route">
    <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="U100" name="checkboxes" id="flexCheckDefault">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                            U100
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="U110" name="checkboxes" id="flexCheckChecked" checked>
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
                            U110
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="U130" name="checkboxes" id="flexCheckDefault">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                            U130
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="U150" name="checkboxes" id="flexCheckChecked" checked>
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
                            U150
                        </label>
                    </div>
</div>

                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**2. In the controller:**

```
   [Route("/your-route")]
    public IActionResult AccessCheckboxes(List<string> checkboxes)
    {
        YourModel model = new();
        model.PTList = checkboxes.ToList();

        return View();
    }
```